# Iteration through an object not returning true

Tags: javascript

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

The function only returns the info of the first user. Never the second. It should return whatever value of the second argument if both are true.

```
 var users = [{
        "name": "Klara",
        "surname": "Johnson",
        "color": "Yellow",
        "preference": ["Hot", "Double", "Sugar free"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Daenerys",
        "surname": "Targaryen",
        "color": "Salmon",
        "preference": ["Iced", "Single", "Chocolate"]
      }
    ];

    function findInfo(name, info) {
      for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (name === users[i].name) {
          if (users[i].hasOwnProperty(info)) {
            return users[i][info]
          } else {
            return "No such info"
          }
        } else {
          return "no such name"
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(findInfo('Klara', 'adsf'))

console.log(findInfo('Daenerys', 'color')) //Expected "Salmon", but log "No such name"
console.log(findInfo('Klara', 'color')) // Yellow
```

Comment: Once a function executes `return`, it is *over*.  You don't get to execute `return` multiple times for the same function call.

Comment: But even though, if I enter findInfo('Daenerys', 'color') I will never get Salmon. It will always goes to "no such name". 

Although, doing it with 'Klara' it returns the right value.

Comment: You are returning from the function before the loop gets to 'Daenerys'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because whenever a return statement is encountered inside a function, the function returns the value specified and exits the function. In your case, it is checking if name of users[i] is same as the one received from arguments. If so, it is checking if it has a property with name "info". As there is no info property, it is simply returning "no property found" and exiting the function without checking for other users. You have to first iterate through the entire array and if user is still not found only then return "no user found". Your code is checking only if the name of first user is equal to parameter. If it is not equal, you are returning "no such name" before iterating through other elements of array.

Working Code:

```
var users = [{
    "name": "Klara",
    "surname": "Johnson",
    "color": "Yellow",
    "preference": ["Hot", "Double", "Sugar free"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Daenerys",
    "surname": "Targaryen",
    "color": "Salmon",
    "preference": ["Iced", "Single", "Chocolate"]
  }
];

function findInfo(name, info) {

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (name === users[i].name) {

      if (users[i].hasOwnProperty(info)) {
        return users[i][info]
      } else {
        return "No such info"
      }
    }
  }
   //if you reach here that means that you have not found user in entire array
  return "no such name"; 
}
console.log(findInfo('Daenerys', 'asdf'))
```

Comment: the variable found is useless, if it is found you would be returning when you find it, check the code right after you set found to 1, you can just have `return "no such name"` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are returning on a for loop possibly before checking all elements, you should be returning at the end of the loop if no user found, anyways a shorter way to do this is:

```js
function findInfo(name, info) {
  const user = users.find(e => e.name === name);
  if(!user) return "No such name";
  return user.hasOwnProperty(info) && user[info] || "No such info";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you return out of the function it doesn't execute for next iteration. You could do something like this though

```js
 var users = [{
        "name": "Klara",
        "surname": "Johnson",
        "color": "Yellow",
        "preference": ["Hot", "Double", "Sugar free"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Daenerys",
        "surname": "Targaryen",
        "color": "Salmon",
        "preference": ["Iced", "Single", "Chocolate"]
      }
    ];

   
    function findInfo(name, info) {
     var userFound = "no user found";
     var userInfo = "no info";
      for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (name === users[i].name) {
           userFound = users[i].name;
          if (users[i].hasOwnProperty(info)) {
            userInfo = users[i][info]; 
            break;
          }
        break;
        }
      }
      return {userFound, userInfo}
    }

    console.log(findInfo('Klara', 'adsf'));

console.log(findInfo('Daenerys', 'color')) ;
console.log(findInfo('Klara', 'color'));
```

Comment: Breaking inside of a for loop isn't the best option, especially when there are better solutions like mine or the other answer, plus he didn't want an object returned, nor did he want to have the hardcoded property `preference`

Comment: Well, the idea was to make the OP's code work with minimal changes so as to asnswer specifically *why* OP's code was not working. I agree on the hardcoded part. I did it just to test. Can update

Comment: Also, returning an object was just an example, it can be name or anything. And why do you think breaking out of the loop is not a good idea? @Karizma

Comment: Mainly because it's unnecessary in this situation and does not provide any benefits vs return, It's a common topic so if you want to learn more I suggest searching it up. `Returning an object was just an example`, i meant how you returned { userFound, userInfo }, not how you returned `user[i].preferences`, OP wanted the property or a string to tell the error, your code always returns an object.

Comment: @Karizma Though I'm not averse to the idea of having multiple returns, in this case they will make the code extremely hard to follow and introduce bugs. `Break`ing out based on the condition is much better option IMO. I specifically meant this object only `{ userFound, userInfo }` it can be name or anything. It's just an example.